# C# - Is there a way to reference an enumeration declared in a generic class from another NON generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, reference, enumeration

Lets say we have the following base class:

```
public abstract class Generic<T>() { }
```

then a child like:

```
public class GenericComparable<T> : Generic<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equal,
        Greater,
        GreaterEqual,
        Less,
        LessEqual,
        NotEqual,
    }
}
```

and another child like:

```
public class GenericEquatable<T> : Generic<T> where T : IEquatable
{
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equal,
        NotEqual,
    }
}
```

Let's imagine, now that I have a class NON generic that has to use one of the enumerations defined in one of the child classes.
For example:

```
public class Example()
{
   public bool ExampleMethod(GenericComparable<>.Comparison comparison)
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

How can I make this code to compile without the need of having the ExampleClass generic as well?

Comment: Nesting types is usually quite rare, being done to either hide implementation details or where the nested type needs to be in a special relationship with the enclosing type. But enums aren't capable of the latter and the former doesn't apply when the nested type is declared `public`

Comment: But why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider your approach.

Note that for each type `T`, `GenericComparable<T>.Comparison` will be a **different**  type, i.e. `typeof(GenericComparable<int>.Comparison) != typeof(GenericComparable<long>.Comparison)`. So there is no single type like `GenericComparable<>.Comparison`.

Can you define the enum types outside of the classes?

Comment: Very technically, this depends on whether you look at it from C# or the CLI perspective. CLI does *not* keep the `T` in scope for the nested type so technically you could refer to `GenericComparable<>.Comparison`. But C# enforces separate nested types, so it redeclares `T` on the nested type also. See ECMA-335 Section I.9.1

Comment: that's exactly my problem, Charlieface. If C# would just allow the usage of GenericComparable<> this would have been much simpler to solve.

Comment: ok, Klaus Gütter, i didn't actually think about the fact that each enum would have been a separate type. I'm not entirely sure if for what I'm thinking to do that would be an issue (probably not seen that I would never compare instances of generics with a different T type) but it's good to know that I am adding more types that I need to the assembly. I may need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - the following is valid code:

```
class A<T>
{
    public enum B { C, D};
}

class E
{
    public bool Test<T>(A<T>.B b)
    {
        return (b == A<T>.B.D);
    }
}
```

Whether it is a good idea is another matter.

Comment: it's true, this is a valid code and compiles BUT I didn't go for this road because still there is a generic type that needs to be specified when calling it. I would like to know if there is a way to just say to the C# compiler: "Ehi, just use A<>.B... in this context you don't need to now anything about T !!".

Comment: You do not need to specify the type explicitly while calling; the compiler will infer the generic type of the method from the type of the argument. In a case where the argument is an `object`, you can just cast it to `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a non-generic class as the base class of the generic one?

Why define `Generic<T>` in the first place?

Example code (in C#):

```cs
public abstract class Comparable
{
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equal,
        Greater,
        GreaterEqual,
        Less,
        LessEqual,
        NotEqual,
    }
}
```

```cs
public class GenericComparable<T> : Comparable where T : IComparable
{}
```

```cs
public abstract class Equatable
{
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equal,
        NotEqual,
    }
}
```

```cs
public class GenericEquatable<T> : Equatable<T> where T : IEquatable
{}
```

```cs
public class Example
{
   public bool ExampleMethod(Comparable.Comparison comparison)
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Maybe use generic methods instead:

Example code (in C#):

```cs
public abstract class Generic<T>()
{}
```

```cs
public class GenericComparable<T> : Generic<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equal,
        Greater,
        GreaterEqual,
        Less,
        LessEqual,
        NotEqual,
    }
}
```

```cs
public class GenericEquatable<T> : Generic<T> where T : IEquatable
{
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equal,
        NotEqual,
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Example()
{
   public bool ExampleMethod<T>(GenericComparable<T>.Comparison comparison) // generic omittable because of type inference
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Type inference: [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20omit%20the%20type%20argument%20and%20the%20compiler%20will%20infer%20it.)

Comment: the generic base class is because there I will define all the common fields and functionalities of all the derived generic classes. In the real project, I actually have a non-generic base class for the the Generic<T> but I need to make a difference between the Comparison enums defined in each separate hierarchy.